# Передача всех значений сплита в mysql

Tags: java, mysql

Java берет значение введенное из формы input

```
String s = new String(request.getParameter("authorName"));
Пример : authorName = "user1 user2 user3"
```

Затем делает сплит и получает

```
 user1
 user2
 user3
```

как передать все эти значения в одном PreparedStatement

```
query1 = connection.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO authors (author_name) VALUES(?)");
query1.setString(1, AuthorName);
```

если выполнить в такой форме

```
        for (String retval: s.split(" "))
        {
        document.setAuthorName(retval);
        }
```

то он передаёт только последнее значение то есть

```
user3
```

а необходимо все передать + количество сплит строк динамично.

Comment: А что делает функция setAuthorName ? по хорошему в цикле должны выполнятся: `query1.setString(1, retval); query1.executeUpdate();` (взято на основе примеров из http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html)

Comment: это геттеры и сеттеры 
Get позволяет получить значения (читать значения), а Set - записать значения в переменную.

Comment: Т.е. она просто ставит свойство класса в указанное значение. Изменение одной переменной к попаданию инфы в БД обычно не приводит. Вам в цикле надо выполнять то что я написал выше

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если я правильно понял вы хотите разбить строку на части и записать в БД отдельными записями. При этом для ускорения работы хотите воспользоваться одним, заранее подготовленным запросом. Это будет выглядеть так:

```
  String s = "user1 user2 user3";
  PreparedStatement query1 = conn.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO authors (author_name) VALUES(?)");
  for (String retval: s.split(" ")) {
      query1.setString(1, retval);
      query1.executeUpdate();
  }
```

[Пример на www.tutorialspoint.com](http://goo.gl/ORUzqp). Нажать execute, после чего для проверки, внизу в консоли набрать `echo "use test; select * from authors" | mysql -u root -proot`

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант, отправить несколько запросов на добавление значений в таблицу в цикле, где цикл идёт `от i = 0 до i < количество строк полученных сплитом`
А так же можно сделать multiple INSERT, вот ответ на вопрос https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6889065/inserting-multiple-rows-in-mysql